# Binding elements in conditional block

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

The conventional way to reference an HTML element is Svelte is to introduce a variable and `bind:this` the element to the variable. Like this

```html
<script>
  let divName;
</script>

<div bind:this={divName}></div>
```

In this way we can use the variable `divName` to reference that element and use it call functions or applying styles.

I'm facing problems when trying to do the same with an element inside a conditional block. In particular when referencing an element which is just became visible. For example

```html
<script>

function enable(){
  someCondition = true;
  if (someCondition) divName.innerText = 'hello';
}

</script>

{#if someCondition}
  <div bind:this={divName}></div>
{/if}
```

Even if the condition is satisfied, when trying to access the element I get the error `divName is null`.

A workaround is to wait a few milliseconds between making the element visible and actually referencing it. I made a full working example on [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/2aac5073dccf4ce1939716899eaf7fd2?version=4.2.10). In a real application, this doesn't always works, plus it's not extremely nice.

I was wondering if anyone know the reason for this and what is the correct way to handle these situations. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a reference to an element when it's created you can use an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#use-action)

[tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions) / [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/adding-parameters-to-actions)

```
<script>
    let visible = false
    
    function handleVisible(node) {
        console.log(node)
    }
</script>

<button on:click={() => visible = !visible}>
  click
</button>

{#if visible}
    <div use:handleVisible>...</div>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example it's probably better to not bind an element in a conditional block but if you're asking in general how to easily update the bound element after it's bound, this would work:

```html
<script>
let divName;
let someCondition;

$: {
  if (divName) {
    divName.innerText = 'hello';
  }
}

function enable() {
  someCondition = true;
}
</script>

<button on:click={enable}>Enable</button>

{#if someCondition}
  <div bind:this={divName}></div>
{/if}
```

I don't know how to do it in the new Svelte syntax yet but the idea is that the "divName.innerText" becomes a computed value that depends on whether or not divName is truthy.  The outer condition of "someCondition" will control the divName element and divName controls divName.innerText.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is to use Svelte's reactivity and wait for the `divTrue` binding to exist:

```
<script>
    let check = true;
    let divTrue;

    function toggle() {
        check = !check;
    }

    $: if (divTrue) {
        divTrue.innerText = 'you can see me';
    }
</script>

<button on:click={toggle}>Toggle</button>
{#if check}
    <div bind:this={divTrue}></div>
{/if}
```

I am guessing your are simplifying your code for this question, but I am having a hard time understanding why you would set the text via an element's innerText property rather than just putting it in your markup:

```
{#if check}
    <div>you can see me</div>
{/if}
```

Comment: You are correct, I'm simplifying what I actually have to do, I just put a working example with the bare minimum

Comment: Either way, using the code in my answer should solve your issue. I tested it in the REPL

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for Svelte framework to update the DOM before accessing it. Try this:

```
<script>
  import { tick } from 'svelte'

  async function enable(){
    someCondition = true;

    // Wait for svelte to update the DOM and then do your work
    await tick()

    // No need for the condition
    divName.innerText = 'hello';
  }

</script>

{#if someCondition}
  <div bind:this={divName}></div>
{/if}
```